# Java go to next image and back with same Button

Tags: java, image, swing, button, if-statement

I'm trying to display another image with 1 button and go back to previous image with same button.

```
private void button2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                        
    if (labelIcon == labelIcon)
       centerLabel.setIcon(labelicon2); 

    if (labelIcon == labelicon2)
       centerLabel.setIcon(labelIcon);
}
```

I'm stuck with if changing only to another image and not going back. Do I need to get label properties somehow (don't know how) to execute second if statement or i need some kind of loop?
I can do it with 2 buttons but I think it can be done with 1. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `int` that keeps track of which image you are on, then if it's on 1, you change to 2, if it's on 2, you change to 1.

i.e.

```
 int imageNumber = 1;

 ...

 if (imageNumber == 1)
 {
  //change image to image 2
  //also change imageNumber to 2
 }
 else if (imageNumber == 2)
 {
  //change image to image 1
  //also change imageNumber to 1
 }
```

Comment: A boolean would be better.

Comment: It would in this case but if they want to add another image, then there'd need to be a change to a numbered variable so I suggested `int` as a starting point.

Comment: No. The OP states that the same button should be used. If there were three images, it wouldn't be possible to use the same button.

Comment: Can you explain a Little bit more with int. I should compare if i ==1 set image1 or if i ==2 set image 2?

Comment: It would if the intention was to step through and back through the images. Either way, if the intention is that there are only ever going to be two images then I suspect this program is quite a small one and the efficiency and storage benefit of a boolean isn't going to make much of a difference.

Comment: But there would be no point of using an int, so why use an int?

Comment: int would be `ìf (int1==1) then {//set to image 2}`, etc.  Boolean would be `if (bool1) then {//set to image 2}`

Comment: Because -like I've said- an int allows extension.

Comment: And like I've said, the OP states that the same button should be used. If there were three images, using the same button wouldn't be possible, thus using an int isn't necessary.

Comment: Thus we are repeating ourselves, you have stated your objection, I have stated my reply.

Comment: @Troubleshoot of course you can use a single button to rotate around an infinite number of images if you want to.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (labelIcon == labelIcon)
```

this code will always return TRUE becouse you are comparing the same object.
I think you ment something like

```
Icon labelIcon = centerLabel.getIcon();
if (labelIcon == this.labelIcon)
centerLabel.setIcon (labelicon2);
if (labelIcon == this.labelicon2)
        centerLabel.setIcon(labelIcon);
    }
```

Comment: Use .equals when comparing objects.

Answer (score -1):

Since the previous three answers all have their faults, here's mine. Use a boolean to check if the button has been clicked.

```
private boolean clicked = false;

private void button2ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {   //importing stuff is always nice...                                      
  if (!clicked) {
    centerLabel.setIcon (labelicon2); 
    clicked = true;
  } else {
    centerLabel.setIcon(labelIcon);
    clicked = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this has been down-voted... anyone care to explain?

Comment: While very minorly more efficient.  This solution is not extensible and leads to slightly less readable code. The phrase "If not clicked" isn't immediately obvious as "If image 1 is shown".

Comment: Actually, I was a little harsh in down voting.  It wont let me remove though.

Comment: As I have stated, no solution is extensible as the OP clearly states he wants to use one button. This code isn't less readable than using an int. Down-voting is meant for answers of poor quality.

Comment: If you put an edit into your post, I can remove the down vote.